# Currying for functions with n (3 or more) arguments?

Tags: haskell, lisp, currying

For functions with three or more arguments, how does `currying` work?

I searched over SO and Google. Concrete examples given in e.g. [What is 'Currying'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying) ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying are about binary functions `f (x, y)`.

In that case,  `g = curry f` takes one parameter and produces a unary function `(f x)`.

My question is:

How do we extend this consistently to a n-parameter function, e.g. `f3 (x,y,z)`? (f3: X->Y->Z->U)

If the `curry` operation is treated as a higher order function, it can't directly apply to `f3`, because `curry` expects a function of type `(X,Y) -> Z`, and the argument of `f3` is a triple, not a pair. The same issue arises with a function `fn` that takes an n-tuple.

One solution might be to equate `(x,y,z)` and `(x,(y,z))`, then `curry` seems to apply.  Then `curry f3 = (f3 x)` is of type `(Y,Z) -> U`. But is this how curry is supposed to be?

Comment: You might like the tuple package, specifically [`Data.Tuple.Curry`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tuple-0.3.0.2/docs/Data-Tuple-Curry.html). If your response is, "GROSS!", well, you're not alone.

Comment: @DanielWagner I laughed. Sometimes I wish tuples were defined as `T a1 (T a2 ..))` with `data T a b = T a !b`, possibly with some ad hoc optimization to recover a good performance.

Comment: Racket's implementation is interesting: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=curry#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Ffunction..rkt%29._curry%29%29

Comment: I've rolled my own `uncurry3` and `uncurry4` functions; I haven't found a need for 5+ yet.

Answer (score 3):

> If the curry operation is treated as a higher order function, it can't directly apply to f3, because curry expects a function of type (X,Y) -> Z, and the argument of f3 is a triple, not a pair. The same issue arises with a function fn that takes an n-tuple.

There are aspects of your question that include much of the strong typing of Haskell that aren't present in most Lisps.  For instance, an easy n-ary **curry** could be defined as:

```
(defun curry (function first-argument)
  (lambda (&rest args)
    (apply function first-argument args)))
```

```
CL-USER> (let ((f (curry (curry (lambda (x y z)
                                  (* x (+ y z)))
                                2)
                         3)))
           (mapcar f '(1 2 3 4 5)))
; (8 10 12 14 16)
```